# Writing a Script to open files with faketime

Tags: scripts

Do to a specific software company dropping Linux support entirely. I would like to write a script that takes the place of the executable (ex. runme) and starts the program with faketime. so that I don't get the time expiration error. The problem I am having is I would like it to start the default program with the file I double clicked in gnome file manager.
So what I have done already is I found the executable and renamed it (mv runme RM) I then created a script file called runme in that same directory, in this file I wrote. (faketime '2019-12-01 08:15:42'  /opt/runme/Linux/RM) So now the script file executes the original program but with an older date. Now if I double click on a file where runme is the default app the program runme opens with no problem but does not open the file I clicked on, instead it just opens the default blank file. Is there an options I can add so the file I double clicked will open in the default app through this script?

Thank you for you time,
JShel
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Gnome 3.36.3

Comment: when you double click on a file to open, usually the `.desktop` file associated with the app will launch the file. You will need to modify or create a new .desktop file where `Exec=` uses your script file. BTW, if you're going to modify a desktop file, they're located in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`, if you're going to create a new one, place it in `~/.local/share/applications`

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if you have a script and you want to pass the arguments through to another program, you have to add:

```
"$@"
```

onto the end. Like if I had a script to do an ls -l, it would look like this:

```
ls -l "$@"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to pass the filename through to the program you are running.  Instead of renaming the executable, why not change the file association to run the faketime command and pass the filename?